# HTML table element cell or columns

Tags: html

Reading the [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#table-model) it seems that there is an important difference 
between a cell and a column so the `td` element is a cell
and not a column... but in almost all books the terms are used
in the same way.

So what's the true?

Comment: If you are placing two cells beside each other, you will have columns…

Comment: Please cite a book that does not make a distinction between a cell and a column.

Answer (score 2):

A `td` is a [cell](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp) in a table.

The authors are probably just referring to it as a "column" since all the cells on the vertical axis comprise the entire column